# Does encapsulating a statement in a transaction include the triggers it fires?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, transactions, consistency

I have an `INSERT` that will fire a `TRIGGER` which will `UPDATE` an attribute on another `TABLE`. I need to make sure that if the `INSERT` is successful and the `UPDATE` inside the `TRIGGER` isn't then the whole thing should be rolled back.

Does encapsulating the `INSERT` in a transaction guarantee this?

If not, how can I do this?

Comment: yes, it should. why don't you just try?..

Comment: @VaoTsun How do you normally force a trigger to fail in order to test this?

Comment: just add condition to update?.. e.g. `update blah set blah where case when new.some_column = 4 then 1/0 else new.some_other_column end` so when you operate on row where some_column = 4 it will die with exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger is part of the database transaction that contains the original `INSERT`.

Any error inside the transaction (that is not handled) will cause **the whole transaction** to be rolled back, just like nothing ever happened. That will include the `INSERT` that caused the trigger to run.

So there is nothing you have to do; it will work the way you want out of the box.

You can explicitly handle an error inside a transaction by setting `SAVEPOINT`s and using `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` (or by using a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` block in PL/pgSQL, which does the same under the hood).

To trigger an exception, either run an SQL statement that causes an error (like `SELECT 1/0`) or use the `RAISE EXCEPTION` statement in PL/pgSQL (there are similar ways for other procedural languages).

Comment: So I don't even need to put the insert inside a transaction?

Comment: Right. Every statement is in a transaction (by default, every statement in its own transaction). The trigger runs in the same transaction. Database transactions are cool, aren't they?